Failed Order Payment Not Reverting MSI Inventory Quantity in Magento 2
I'm experiencing an issue with my Magento 2 website concerning inventory management using Multi Source Inventory (MSI). Whenever there is a failed transaction via a specific payment gateway, the inventory quantity for the product is deducted as expected. However, unlike successful transactions, the deducted quantity for failed transactions does not revert back to the stock automatically.
If a customer attempts to purchase a product (e.g., SKU1234) and the payment fails, the quantity of the item is reduced in the MSI inventory. For example, if the initial quantity was 6 pcs, the salable quantity shows as 5 pcs, even though the payment did not succeed and the order itself is neither registered in the backend as an order nor shown as cancelled. We only receive a notification about the failed payment via email.
Please advise and thank you
